# ¿Por qué los elementos de mi layout aparecen incompletos al momento de ejecutar mi app? - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xml, android-layout

Tengo un `CardView` con "items" dentro, y al momento de instalar mi aplicación los "items" y el `CardView` salen recortados del lado derecho.
Así se ve desde la ventana de diseño:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así se ve cuando instalo la aplicación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí está mi XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#E2E2E2"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="5dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="5dp"
    >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="376dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgvposter"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvnombre"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Hola"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnverdetalles"
        android:layout_width="115dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_style"
        android:text="ver detalles"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eso pasa cuando programas un tamaño estático de los componentes y lo aplicas en un dispositivo de menor resolución.
Para solucionar el problema debes cambiar tu linea `android:layout_width="376dp"` por `android:layout_width="match_parent"`, esto tomará en cuenta el tamaño del contenedor padre o pantalla, y se ajustará al tamaño por defecto.
Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias! Desconocía el dato.

Answer (score 4):

En tu `CardView` tienes definido un ancho "wrap_content" , además en tu `Linearlayout` tienes definido una medida fija de 376dp, lo cual es incorrecto si deseas que tu `layout` se despliegue correctamente en varias densidades/tamaños:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="376dp">
```

usa `android:layout_width="match_parent"`, este sería el `layout` corregido:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#E2E2E2"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="5dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgvposter"
            android:layout_width="85dp"
            android:layout_height="85dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvnombre"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Hola"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnverdetalles"
            android:layout_width="115dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_style"
            android:text="ver detalles"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo! Aprecio que hayas corregido el XML.

Comment: @weirzetig29 un placer ayudarte amigo, saludos.

Comment: Hola @Antonio veo que quitaste como respuesta aceptada, no te sirvió mi respuesta?, saludos.